# Pop out all values in the Stack, multi them then Push back to the Stack

Tags: algorithm, linked-list, stack

Here's what i came up with, i want to Pop every values in my Stack, multiple them and Push back in old Stack. It will look like this:

- Push: 2, 3, 5 in the Stack. ( All the values are Primenumber ).
- Pop: 2, 3, 5.
- Calculate: 2 * 3 * 5 = 30.
- Push: 30 in the Stack.

---

Here is my source code:

```
struct Node{
    int data;
    Node *next;
};
    
bool isEmpty(Node *head){
    if (head == NULL) return true;
    else return false;
}


bool Sphenic(Node*current,int i=2){
    if(current->data ==2 ){
        return (current->data ==2) ? true:false;
    }
    if(current -> data == 1) return false;
    if(current->data % i ==0) return false;
    if(i*i> current->data) return true;

    return Sphenic(current,i+1);
}


void Push(Node *&head,int number){
    Node *temp = new Node;
    temp->data = number;
    if(Sphenic(temp,2)==true){
        temp->next = head;
        head=temp;
    }
    
    else{
        cout<<"Your input is not Primenumber";
    }
    
}

void Insert(Node *&head,int number){
    Node *temp = new Node;
    temp->data = number;
    temp->next = head;
    head=temp;
}



void Pop(Node *&head){
    Node *temp = head;
    Node *res = head;
    res->data= res->data * res->next->data * res->next->next->data;
    Insert(head,res->data);
    cout<<res->data;
    head = temp->next;
    free(temp);
    
}

void display(Node *current){
    if(current==NULL){
        cout<<"Your List is NULL";
    }
    else{
        while(current!=NULL){
            cout<<current->data<<" ";
            current= current->next;      
        }
    }
}



int main(){
    Node *head = NULL;
    int T=3;
    for(int i=0;i<T;i++){
        int number;cin>>number;
        Push(head,number);
    }
    display(head);
    Pop(head);
    Pop(head);
    Pop(head);
    cout<<endl;
    display(head);  
}
```

My problem is, when i pop 3 values ( in main part ) then display the list, and it show nothing. Can anyone suggest me the idea to solve this? I know my code is little bit messy but if you want more details just leave a comment.

Comment: Why do you need to push the values unto a stack when the first thing you do is pop them again? Can you better explain what the goal is? What is the expected output?

Comment: The expected output is 30.  The goal is to find sphenic number. Sphenic number = a*b*c where a,b,c are distinct prime number. The final result, i mean the final stack must contain only a sphenick number ( in here is 30 )

Comment: I don't understand the utility of the stack. Seems overly complex to find the first three prime numbers and then multiply them. What is `Sphenic` supposed to do?

Comment: in your main function, you must be passing address of head, than just the pointer. when you enter first 2, and then 3, did you debug and check if Push() function is really working.